# How to select multiple distinct values and max values in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which logs activity on a particular rowid. Sample data is

```
rowid   activityid  status
323767  241288  Compromise
323767  227405  Untraced
323767  226356  Untraced
323767  226218  Reinvestigation ordered by court
323767  226217  Untraced
319859  225642  Reinvestigation ordered by court
319859  222568  Reinvestigation ordered by court
319807  222551  
319807  222524  
305458  204104  Reinvestigation ordered by court
305458  204002  Convicted
```

I need to get the max value of activityid for a single rowid..like as below

```
rowid   activityid  status
323767  241288  Compromise
319859  225642  Reinvestigation ordered by court
319807  222551  
305458  204104  Reinvestigation ordered by court
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include information about what you've tried so far in questions (e.g. code you've written, information you've found from research).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution solution based on standard ANSI SQL would be using a co-related sub-query

```
select t1.rowid, 
       t1.activityid,
       t1.status
from the_table t1
where t1.activityid = (select max(t2.activityid) 
                       from the_table t2
                       where t1.rowid = t2.rowid)
order by rowid;
```

or (more efficiently) a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select rowid, 
         activityid,
         max(activityid) over (partition by rowid) as max_activity,
         status
  from the_table 
) t 
where activityid = max_activity
rowid;
```

however in Postgres this can be done more efficiently using `distinct on` operator

```
select distinct on (rowid) rowid, activityid, status
from the_table
order by rowid, activityid desc
```

The solution with `distinct on` is going to be the fastest, followed by the solution using a window function and the co-related subquery is most probably going to be the slowest.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select tableA.rowid,tableA.activityid,table.status
from  (select rowid,max(activityid)  as activityid 
        from table 
       group by rowid) tableA,table
where tableA.activityid = table.activityid
```